# iPhone 5S iOS7 Responsive Email Contiguous Image Height Issue

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios8, responsive-design, html-email

As soon as I started coding responsive emails, I noticed that contiguous images (all with the same original height) in a HTML table row didn't always remain the same height when being responsively scaled.  That's a big problem for me because the email layouts that I am working on are image heavy and have to be tightly aligned.  Uneven height images break the layout.  I eventually came up with the solution presented here:  http://am-samples.gear.host/iPhone5S-iO7-issue.html

Navigate to that URL and resize the browser to see the responsive scaling in action.

Here are the main snippets in case you can't navigate to the URL above:

**Table that has the contiguous images**

```
<table class="100p" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#7fff00" style="background-color: #7fff00;">
    <tr>
        <td class="100p" align="center" width="100%" valign="top">
            <div>
                <table class="100p" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="100p" width="100%" align="left" valign="top">
                            <span width="26.09375%" style="width: 26.09375%; display: inline-block;">
                                <img id="ourStory" class="responsiveImage" src="http://am-samples.gear.host/images/bottom-our-story.png" border="0" style="display: block;" />
                            </span><span width="19.6875%" style="width: 19.6875%; display: inline-block;">
                                <img id="recipes" class="responsiveImage" src="http://am-samples.gear.host/images/bottom-recipes.png" border="0" style="display: block;" />
                            </span><span width="25.15625%" style="width: 25.15625%; display: inline-block;">
                                <img id="seafood" class="responsiveImage" src="http://am-samples.gear.host/images/bottom-seafood.png" border="0" style="display: block;" />
                            </span><span width="29.0625%" style="width: 29.0625%; display: inline-block;">
                                <img id="giftCards" class="responsiveImage" src="http://am-samples.gear.host/images/bottom-giftcards.png" border="0" style="display: block;" />
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS classes referenced**

```
.responsiveImage {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    border: none;
}

*[class="100p"] {
                width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
}
```

I've stripped the code down to the essentials just to clearly present the issue.  If you take a look at the source code, you'll see that the top and bottom black strips are just tables with a black background color.  The red strip is actually made up of contiguous images.  The original height of all the images is the same.  Because of that I expected the height of all the images to scale equally.  The table that contains the images has a background color of florescent green.  That way, in Litmus, it is easy to see if the height of any of the images is different.

I've tested this solution in Litmus and it works fine on the email clients that I am interested in except two:  iPhone 5S (iOS7 and iOS8).  Here is a screenshot of the result in iPhone 5S and iOS7 (iOS 8 produces a similar result) : http://am-samples.gear.host/images/iPhone5S-iOS7-issue.jpg

So the problem is that when scaling, sometimes the image heights are not all equal.  Any ideas on how to fix this on the iPhone 5S?

Answer (score 0):

Different widths with the same height makes the images a different scale, which means that as they shrink through the 100% w x auto h, they will differ in height.

To retain consistent height/width through mobile I would make sure that the scale is identical.  E.g. make all images 100px x 50px. (you can use percents here if you wish too)

The only other option I can really offer from what I see is a defined height to force each to that amount, but in HTML email, this is not likely to be followed by the email clients processors.